# firefox specific error when using javascript date

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I am using jinja2 to write a date in a javascript variable like this

```
var tomorrowsDate_string = new Date('{{ group.next_meeting }}');
```

this works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I get an error. When printing to the console with console.log() I see

```
tomorrowsDate_string =  Invalid Date
```

The date I am trying to parse here has the following format

```
group.next_meeting =  2016-08-20 10:00:00
```

I noticed that I can avoid the error when using 2016-08-20T10:00:00 instead, where the extra T specified UTC. The date is actually in UTC anyway. Does anybody know how I can parse a date from jinja2 to javascript including the timezone?

SOLUTION: Thanks to adeneo who commented below... the working solution for both, Firefox and Chrome is

```
var tomorrowsDate_string = new Date('{{ group.next_meeting.year }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.month }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.day }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.hour }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.minute }}');
```

Comment: You pass valid arguments to `new Date`, I'd suggest `new Date(2016, 7, 20, 10)`

Comment: If you come up with the answer to your own question, post the answer as an answer, and then mark the answer as the accepted answer.  This closes the question, instead of leaving it marked as needing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to adeneo who commented above... the working solution for both, Firefox and Chrome is

var tomorrowsDate_string = new Date('{{ group.next_meeting.year }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.month }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.day }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.hour }}', '{{ group.next_meeting.minute }}');